# Use xpath to find empty cells in a table

Tags: python, xpath

I have a bit of html code that looks like this:

```
<td class="Label">France</td>
<td class="Label">French</td>
<td class="Label"><img src="frenchflag.jpg></td>
<td class="Label">Germany</td>
<td class="Label"></td>
<td class="Label"><img src="germanflag.jpg></td>
```

I'm webscraping with python & selenium and I want a list that looks like this:

```
['France','French','Germany','N/A']
```

So I can't use the class name to identify these, because they're all the same.  Nor can I use

```
 if element.text() is None:
mylist.append('N/A')
```

because that will also pull in the tags with just the image in them, which I need to just ignore.

Is there no such thing as .contents() or similar for xpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This xpath will reject items with subelements. You can then scan the list adding N/A to results without text elements.

```
td[@class="Label"][not(*)]
```